# Laravel 6.x. Problem is Login Page, When I'm Creating Panels

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Laravel 6.x. Now Problem is the First-time Login successfully working fine It redirects to the site where I need to be but second or more time login failed It redirect to the login page. Why?
In **RedirectIfAuthenticated** file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

In **RouteServiceProvider** file

```
public const HOME = '/index/dashboard/';
```

In **HomeController** file

```
public function index()
    {
        if ((Auth::user())->user_role == 'admin')
        {
            $title='admin dashboard';
            return view('admin-dashboard',compact('title'));
        }
        else{
            return view('login-page');
        }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code...

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you for sure without more details. but one thing you can check is that you have set the right redirect url in the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware.

Comment: Yes `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`, check where you are redirecting the user